При установке арч Линукс выходит ошибка с grub
gnu grub version 2:2.12-2 minimal bash-like line editing is supported. for the first word, tab lists possible command completions. anywhere else tab lists possible device or file completions. to enable less(1) - like paging, "set pager = 1"
Вылазит такая ошибка

Как именно ставили арч. Какими командами? Если из инсталлера, то с какими настройками?
